# Laravel executes the POST route upon loading page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So I have a form on the front page:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('', array(), true))) }}
        <p>
            {{Form::label('author') }}
            {{Form::text('author') }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{Form::label('title') }}
            {{Form::text('title') }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{Form::label('message') }}
            {{Form::text('message') }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ Form::submit() }}
        </p>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Then these are my routes:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    /* unrelated stuff here */
});

Route::post('/', function()
{
    /* testing */
    print_r("DONE!");
    exit;
});
```

So I am basically trying to test whether my form submission works or not. And it doesn't. For some reason the POST method is being executed once I load the front page instead of when the form is submitted. Why is that and how can I fix this?

Comment: Change the route name of your post method `/test` like that and `URL::to('/test')`.

Comment: @aldrin27 It worked, but how can I make sure it is executed on the front page and returned to home page? Basically, I add a post by using the form on the front page, and the newly added posts appears on top of my post list (after added to the database). How can I prevent from being redirected to /test ?

Comment: `return Redirect::to('/');`

Answer (score 1):

Your form url should be specified to post to **/** -

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/')) }}
```

In order to redirect back to the homepage you should modify your post method like this -

```
Route::post('/', function()
{
    /* testing */
    print_r("DONE!");
    return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects) is the documentation for redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use dirrefent route:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('/submitForm', array(), true))) }}
```

And then:

```
Route::post('/submitForm', function()
{
    /* testing */
    print_r("DONE!");
    return redirect()->route('/');
});
```